# Return multiple rows for every row in a DataFrame in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, iteration, query-optimization

Here is the task i would like to perform, i have list of about 7000 sites and 50 categories each which has a sales plan per combination every month. I want to convert this monthly plan into daily and compare it with actuals and create a power BI visual, for this i need to convert the plan data to daily.

here is the sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2],
                    'Month':[1,1],
                   'Plan':[310,620],
                'Month_start_date': ['2020-01-01','2020-01-01']})
print(df)

df['Month_start_date'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['Month_start_date'], format='%Y/%m/%d')
                     .dt.to_period('m').dt.to_timestamp())

df = df.set_index('Month_start_date')
```

Now the function i want to apply on each row returns more number of rows, here is a sample:

```
start = '2020-01-01'
end = '2020-01-05'
dates = pd.date_range(start, end, freq='D')
dates

df= df.reindex(dates,method = 'ffill')
```

This returns a error as Index has duplicate values

```
ValueError: cannot reindex a non-unique index with a method or limit
```

Here is my desired output

```
            ID  Month  Plan
2020-01-01   1      1   310
2020-01-02   1      1   310
2020-01-03   1      1   310
2020-01-04   1      1   310
2020-01-05   1      1   310
2020-01-01   2      1   620
2020-01-02   2      1   620
2020-01-03   2      1   620
2020-01-04   2      1   620
2020-01-05   2      1   620
```

Since the number of combinations i have to run this for is about 800K in reality running it on loops(using .iterrows() ) takes forever to complete and seems very inefficient.

Also tried using .groupby.apply() function. but it doesnt allow me to return a dataframe for every row(table df).

Suggestions needed to improve this process.

Comment: But do you actually really need to [create fake daily numbers from spreading the monthly data over `.index.daysinmonth`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61517215/changing-monthly-values-to-daily-by-evenly-distributing-between-dates), and thereby create 30x more records, without any extra information? Why don't you just use <monthly number>/daysinmonth directly? Unless you show us a reason you need to, I don't think you need it, and it keeps your dataframe compact. Show us the ultimate calculation you're performing, dont just say *"I need to create thousands of duplicate rows in my table"*.

Comment: Sure @smci. i will edit the question per your suggestion

Comment: Yes please. Show us the higher context in which this code occurs. Otherwise we're working blind.

Comment: I have tried to add business context to the question. Please do let me know what you think.

Comment: I'm sorry but *"I want to convert this monthly plan into daily for a daily report."* doesn't seem a compelling reason to duplicate your data 30x. If all your code is ever doing is dividing a monthly total by the number of days in that month (and you won't ever have any actual real daily data), why can't you just show the numerators and denominator? (By the way do you really want to distribute 1/7 to every day of thweek including Sat & Sunday? Not like 1/5 to every workday, or every non-holiday workday?)

Comment: I understand how it looks, lemme try to rephrase the question a little further to see if i can make more sense.

Answer (score -1):

The sort_values() function should hopefully achieve what you're looking for:

`df.sort_values(by=df.index, inplace =True)`

Or if your dates had a column name you'd just change it to the df's column name, and you could even pair it with groupby to create dataframes just for certain sorted groups since your dataset is so large. I hope this helps a little!

Comment: Thanks for answering Marcos, am getting this error. KeyError: DatetimeIndex(['2020-01-01', '2020-01-01'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Month_start_date', freq=None) - basically a check for duplicates error. Moreover, i dont understand the solution, can you explain a little further?